# Getting search values by clicking links in application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a row of cities at the top of a layout. I also have a sidebar with a list of categories. In a view that is rendered within this layout, I'd like to query results of a model with category and location fields, based on which city has been selected, and by which category is most recently clicked. [image]

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this. I guess I'd like the city buttons to function like radio buttons, so that when a category is clicked, it is still using the last selected location to query the results. I'm also not sure how to pass the clicked button's value to the Offers model's search function:

```
def self.search(query, query2, query3)
    where("title like ?", "%#{query}%").
    where("category = ?", "%#{query2}%").
    where("city = ?", "%#{query3}%")
end
```

This is the last step in finishing a large project for me, and any help would be greatly appreciated. If all else fails, I'll just end up using two dropdowns for category and location, but I'd really like to get this working.

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript to update the results whenever a category is clicked.

Comment: I'm fine with having the page reload, I just want to make sure both category and location are used in the search.

Comment: What do your params look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Routing**

You'll basically need to define a [`route`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to handle this - allowing you to pass a series of [`parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) through your links to your controller, allowing you bring back the data as defined by the links

Whether you handle this through plain `HTTP`, or through `Javascript`, it's the same process `link > controller > response`

I would do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :offers do
   collection do
      get :search
   end
end
```

This will allow you to create your links as follows:

```
<% @cities.each do |city| %>
   <%= link_to city.name, offers_search_path(city: city.name) %>
<% end %>
```

This should create the link: `domain.com/offers/search?city=scarborough`

--

**Controller**

When you have a link like the one above, your controller will then be able to handle the `city` [param](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters), allowing you to perform a conditional search as follows:

```
#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
Class OffersController < ApplicationController
   def search
       @result = Offer.search params[:city] #-> considering you want to use a class method
   end
end
```

--

**Ajax**

If you wanted to perform the search via ajax, you'd do all of the above except you'd handle the link as a `remote` one:

```
<%= link_to city.name, offers_search_path(city: city.name), remote: true %>
```

This will send an ajaxified request to your controller, which you'll be able to handle as follows:

```
#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
Class OffersController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html
   def search
       @result = Offer.search params[:city]
       respond_with @result
   end
end
```